# Endomorphism and Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

In the context of linear maps I need help to understand the notation used in this exercise and the general method to solve it.

> In the Euclidean space $\mathbb R^3$ with the standard inner product, consider the endomorphism $f : \mathbb R^3 \rightarrow \mathbb R^3$ defined by
>
> $$f(1,0,1) = (1,4,1), \,\, f(1,0,-1) = (-3,0,3), \,\,f(0,1,0)=(2,-1,2).$$
>
> Find the *associated* $f^*$.

Since I'm translating directly from greek notes I'm not sure if the word "*associated*" is correct in this context. Nowhere in my notes does the author gives the definition of $f^*$. This is the major problem that I have and therefore, this is my first question:

$(Q1)$ What is the precise definition of $f^*$? Specifically, what does the exercise ask us to find? Also, if the word "*associated*" is not correct, what is the correct one?

The author gives the following quick solution to the exercise:

**Solution**. The matrix of $f$ in the standard basis $B$ of $\mathbb R^3$ is

$$A = M_B^B(f) = \begin{pmatrix}-1 & 2 & 2\\2 & -1 & 2\\2 & 2 &-1\end{pmatrix}.$$

Since the matrix $A$ is symmetric it follows that $f = f^*$.

Therefore, the *associated* $f^* : \mathbb R^3 \rightarrow \mathbb R^3$ of $f$ is exactly $f$.

---

$(Q2)$ At the moment the above solution doesn't make any sense to me. I can see that the matrix $A$ is symmetric but I have no idea how to find it, what it actually represents, how it is connected to the exercise and what to conclude from it.

I'm looking for answers to $(Q1)$ and $(Q2)$ which will allow me to understand the exercise and solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a linear transformation, $f$ can be represented through a matrix, whose columns are the images of the standard basis vectors. By linearity \begin{align}f(1,0,0)&=f\left(\frac12(1,0,1)+\frac12(1,0,-1)\right)=^{\text{linearity of $f$}}\\[0.2cm]&=\frac12f(1,0,1)+\frac12f(1,0,-1)=\frac12(1,4,1)+\frac12(-3,0,3)=(-1,2,2)\end{align} and similarly for $(0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$. That is how he derived matrix $A$. Then $f^*$ is just the [conjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_transpose) of $f$, the word "associated" seems unnecessary. Given the matrix $A$, the conjugate is found through the relation $$A^*=\overline{A}^T=A^T$$ since $A$ is real. For any $x,y \in \mathbb R^3$ it satisfies the relation $\langle Ax,y\rangle=\langle x,A^*y\rangle$ where $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ stands for the inner-product in $\mathbb R^3$, but most likely you do not need that in this question.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed and clear explanation. It is extremely helpful. Since I'm new to this subject I would like to make sure I understand the conclusion. We know that if $A$ is a any symmetric matrix, then $A=A^T$. In the context of this exercise, if the matrix $A$ was not symmetric, I would have to compute $A^T$ and this would be $f^*$. Is that correct?

Comment: @Elix Yes, exactly, assuming the elements in $A$ are real numbers, then $A^T=A^*$. But here symmetry implied $A=A^T$ and so it saved you the "computation" of $A^T$. Generally, that the columns of $A^T$ are just the rows of $A$ and in the same order (first row of $A$ is first column of $A^T$ etc.), so there would not be much to compute even if $A$ was not symmetric.

Comment: @Elix to be strict, the $f^{\ast}$ is the linear map whose matrix with respect to the standard basis is $A^T$. This is not exactly the same as saying it is $A^T$. Often one glosses over this, but in the context of such an excercise it may be that failure to account for this distinction costs full credit.

Answer (score 3):

Q1) Can't be certain, but I believe $f^*$ is the adjoint ( conjugate transpose )

Q2) There would be many ways to solve it.  I would do it this way: 
The first column with respect to $B$ is $f(1,0,0)$.  Since $f$ is linear, this is 
$$
\frac{1}{2}\left(f(1,0,-1) + f(1,0,1)\right) = (-1,2,2)
$$
Do the same for $f(0,1,0)$ and $f(0,0,1)$

Answer (score 1):

As the other two answers said, $f^{\ast}$ is supposed to be the adjoint of $f$. For real matrices, that effectively just means the transpose.

To find the matrix $F$ of $f$, write the equations in this form:

$$ F \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -3 & 2 \\ 4 & 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 3 & 2\end{pmatrix} $$

See what you have to do to solve for $F$?

Comment: Multiplying both sides by the inverse. Thanks! :)

Answer (score -1):

Basically this explains how to find a matrix representation of a function 
f(1,0,1)=(1,4,1),f(1,0,−1)=(−3,0,3),f(0,1,0)=(2,−1,2).The matrix representation is a transformation matrix which depends upon the basis vectors chosen. So for simplicity we choose the standard basis (1,0,0), (0,1,0) and (0,0,1).Then express the three given functions ( the function vector as taken together) in linear combinations of the basis vectors. So we find the functional values
 f(1,0,1)=(1,4,1),f(1,0,−1)=(−3,0,3),f(0,1,0)=(2,−1,2).
f(1,0,1)=(1,4,1),f(1,0,−1)=(−3,0,3),f(0,1,0)=(2,−1,2).
This expressed as a matrix becomes A = M(f) as above. The matrix is symmetric because of linearity of the function f